# Error with catching std::runtime_error as std::exception

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

we have a funny problem with try catch and std::runtime_error.
Can someone explain to me why this is returning "Unknown error" as output ?
Thanks very much for helping me !

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

int magicCode()
{
    throw std::runtime_error("FunnyError");
}

int funnyCatch()
{
    try{
        magicCode();
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        throw e;
    }

}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        funnyCatch();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what();
    }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: It prints "FunnyError" for me, using Visual C++ 2010. Which compiler are you using?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem is with this line. Because `throw` with an expression uses the static type of that expression to determine the exception thrown, this slices the exception object constructing a new `std::exception` object copying only the base object part of the `std::runtime_error` that `e` is a reference to.

```
throw e;
```

To re-throw the caught exception you should always use throw without an expression.

```
throw;
```

Comment: 18 seconds faster ... how does he do it ?!

Comment: Ah, `exception`'s copy constructor doesn't have to preserve `what()`. I didn't realise that.

Comment: Charles, I thought that  throw e; would call the copy constructor std::exception(const std::exception e), which would create a correct copy of the exception ? Is it not the case ?

Comment: Yes, it uses `std::exception`'s copy constructor. No, this won't necessarily result in a 'correct' copy of the exception as `std::exception` is only the base class of the exception that `e` actually refers to.

Comment: Thank you for the complete answer, I have been taught to always rethrow using throw, while investigating an issue, I was curious about why the message returned by what() was not preserved. Thanks to you I know the reason, Charles !

Comment: Up until the draft from March this year, the standard says that the effect of calling `what()` on a copied exception is implementation-defined. As of March (N3090), the `exception` copy constructor must ensure that `strcmp(this->what(), rhs.what()) == 0` after copying an `rhs` with *dynamic* type of `exception`. So it's guaranteed to print "FunnyError" in C++0x as written.

Comment: Exception object slicing is also covered in *More Effective C++*, item 13.

Answer (score 1):

I found a perfect response to this problem:

> C++ makes an explicit distinction between reference and value copy. Use

```
catch (const std::exception& e)
```

> to catch by reference instead of value.

Go give upvotes for the original responder [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631011/how-to-catch-a-genereal-exception-and-show-its-derived-what)

Comment: I didn't catch by value copy.