# how to catch a general exception and show its derived what()

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

The problem happens with code like this:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

try {
    throw  runtime_error("Message");
} catch (exception e) {
    cout << e.what();
}
return 0;
}
```

I expect `Message` to appear. But the result was `std::exception`. I thought the subclass `virtual functions` can be called from the superclass reference. How can fix that?

Comment: you are slicing the exception object

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C++ makes an explicit distinction between reference and value copy. Use

```
catch (const std::exception& e)
```

to catch by reference instead of value.