# XCODE produces Segmentation fault as opposed to Exception

Tags: c++, exception, segmentation-fault

I have a very basic C++ program :-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

  std::cout <<"Welcome .. "<<std::endl;
  try {
    throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Crazy exception"));
  }
  catch(std::exception& e) {

    std::cerr << "error: " << e.what() << "\n";
    exit(0);

    } return 0;

}
```

Whenver  I run this program, instead of an exception I see a `Segmentation fault: 11`
On the debugger, I see `EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)` at the **throw** statement.
I have exceptions enabled on XCODE. Has anyone ever seen this kind of basic error ?

This is really killing me, should I re-install XCODE ? If yes, what's the way for clean install or something

Re-installed XCODE directly from APP STORE. Same issue !! Next is what ? Re-install the whole OSX i believe. Can someone give some clue what "can" be tried before I lounge into a brainless reformatting of the machine ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to catch a genereal exception and show its derived what()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631011/how-to-catch-a-genereal-exception-and-show-its-derived-what) - it should be `catch(std::exception const &e)`?

Comment: Thanks, but If I forgot std:: keyword, it'll create a compilation error. I have the std:: keyword in my code. I updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have executed this program on my mac and it compiled successfully using every type of runtime error in `<stdexcept>`. Which version of Xcode are you running? is it installed from the Apple store or some other website?

If you have installed it from Apple store please update Xcode version to Xcode 8.3.3 and run the code again.

In case you are using it from some other website, then there is a chance that it has a bug. I have also encountered a similar problem before.

There is a simple way to uninstall Xcode from your Mac. Drag Xcode from Finder in Applications and throw it in the Trash and Empty the Trash.

Comment: Re-installed XCODE directly from APP STORE. Same issue

Comment: This is on 8.3.3

Comment: check the gcc version on your mac by typing gcc --version in mac terminal. Send me what it is showing?

Answer (score 0):

Re installed MAC OSX ! And it fixed the issue. 
Surprisingly there can be some OS corruption which may cause this.

Hopefully this would help someone else in future